# Rotary speaker effect for SF2 Organ

Tags: midi, control

I am trying to find software and detailed instructions for creating a rotary speaker effect for  any instruments in an SF2 file.

In other words I need to understand how to EDIT AND SAVE an SF2 file that allows me to control an LFO Amplitude with Midi CC 16, or 17 or whatever - IN REAL TIME-LIVE.

I have tried it in Viena and Polphone without success - if anyone knows how I would really appreciate some detailed instruction.

KPaul

Comment: I realize it isn't really an answer, but if you don't specifically need SF2, SFZ, a free and open text-based sampler format with a free player (Plouge sfortzando) can pull this off quite easily.

Comment: I was looking at Plouge from search results and I'll have a better look - thank you. Unfortunately the target application only uses SF2 files at this time. The app is Audio Evolution Mobile for Android - A very portable and latency free app with instrument tracks for live performance.